# insert FrameNode with ASM

Tags: java, bytecode, java-bytecode-asm

How would i insert that framenode in bytecode?

```
FRAME FULL [java/lang/String [C java/lang/String T I I [C] []
```

My first try was that:

```
mn.instructions.insertBefore(random, new FrameNode(Opcodes.F_FULL, 1 /**IDK**/,
    new Object[]{ "java/lang/String", "[C", "java/lang/String", "T", "I", "I", "[C]" },
    1/**IDK**/, new Object[] { "[C]","[]" }));
```

that didn't work well. Output:

```
    FRAME FULL [[java/lang/String] [java/lang/String]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A stack frame consist of a number of local variables and a number of values on the operand stack. What you are trying to reproduce, is apparently the result of the conversion of that state to a human readable string of the form

`FRAME FULL [list of local variables types] [list of operand stack time types]`

The first thing you have to do, is to identify the brackets from the output format, which requires understanding of the contained type signatures, as a signature starting with an opening bracket like `[C` denotes an array type, i.e. a character array. In other words, some opening brackets are part of the type signatures, others are part of the output format, whereas closing brackets are always part of the output format and never appear in type signatures.

Then, when you have identified the type signatures within the two groups, provide the appropriate count of local variables and operand stack items. In your case you have:

```
FRAME FULL // frame type
[          // start local variables
  java/lang/String
  [C
  java/lang/String
  T
  I
  I
  [C
] // seven local variables specified
[ // start of operand stack
] // empty operand stack
```

But then you have to start thinking about the *meaning* of the type items, which is unfortunately not derivable from a print output and just reproducing the same printout does not necessarily imply correct code.

Namely, the items `T` and `I` could refer to classes having the full qualified names `T` and `I`, respectively, in which case passing `"T"` and `"I"` to `FrameNode` would be correct. However, it’s more likely that they refer to the non-class stack frame types *‹top›* and `int` which must be referred to using predefined `Integer` constants in ASM:

```
new FrameNode(Opcodes.F_FULL, 7, new Object[] {
    "java/lang/String", "[C", "java/lang/String",
    Opcodes.TOP, Opcodes.INTEGER, Opcodes.INTEGER, "[C" }, 0, new Object[0]);
```